# How to get img src URL's from id's children tag with cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I want to get specific's id's children image src data.
With cheer.io I can get HTML data from it with `$("#descTemplate").html();` code, but I want to get it's html codes children's all of image data.

So I tried  `$("#descTemplate").find('img').attr('src');` code but it only returns undefined
Either  `$("#descTemplate").html().find('img').attr('src');` code returns nothing.

```
let searchUrl = 'URL ADDRESS';
await got(searchUrl, {
  timeout: {
    request: 30000,
  },
}).then(async(response) => {
  const $ = cheerio.load(response.body); // HTML data
  // itemDetailImage = $("#descTemplate").html(); // Get HTML part data (Successfully get HTML file)
  itemDetailImage = $("#descTemplate").find('img').attr('src');   // return undefined
  console.log(itemDetailImage);
})
```

[console.log(itemDetailImage)]

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <img src="//127.0.0.1/upload/1647265117250_378688.jpg" data-ke-src="//127.0.0.1/upload/1647265117250_378688.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="//127.0.0.1/upload/1647265118130_300066.jpg" data-ke-src="//127.0.0.1/upload/1647265118130_300066.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="//127.0.0.1/upload/1647265118350_681553.jpg" data-ke-src="//127.0.0.1/upload/1647265118350_681553.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="//127.0.0.1/upload/1647265118885_854027.jpg" data-ke-src="//127.0.0.1/upload/1647265118885_854027.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="//127.0.0.1/upload/1647265119412_530569.png" data-ke-src="//127.0.0.1/upload/1647265119412_530569.png" alt="">
    <img src="//127.0.0.1/upload/1647265119594_158186.jpg" data-ke-src="//127.0.0.1/upload/1647265119594_158186.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="//127.0.0.1/upload/1647265119973_110062.jpg" data-ke-src="//127.0.0.1/upload/1647265119973_110062.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Does `$("#descTemplate")` return the element you expect? Try to log it `console.log($("#descTemplate"));` or `console.log($("#descTemplate").find('img'));`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's not there, but you can try:

```
$("#descTemplate img").get().map(img => $(img).attr('src'))
```